# Organização do eixo x

Tags: r

Fiz um histograma no R porém percebi que o eixo está com um erro, ele ordena -0 como sendo maior que -2 e não segue a sequência, como segue na foto.

Tentei filtrar na base de dados que gerei porém quando classifico do menor numero ao maior ela continua desse jeito, vocês já passaram por algo parecido? Conseguem me ajudar?

```
library("reader")
library("lubridate") 
library("zoo") 
install.packages("dplyr")
install.packages("data.table")
install.packages("ggplot2")
install.packages("zoo")

setwd("C:/Users/Giovanni/Desktop")

dados_ibov <- read.csv('treinosr/Ibovespa_datah.csv',header = TRUE, sep = ",")

data.frame(dados_ibov)

freq <- table(dados_ibov$Var.)

barplot(freq, ylab="Frequência", xlab = "Retornos diários do Ibovespa")
```

**como solicitado:**

```
dput(head(freq, 20))
structure(c(`-0,00%` = 4L, `-0,01%` = 9L, `-0,02%` = 6L, `-0,03%` = 4L, 
`-0,04%` = 9L, `-0,05%` = 9L, `-0,06%` = 10L, `-0,07%` = 6L, 
`-0,08%` = 13L, `-0,09%` = 4L, `-0,10%` = 8L, `-0,11%` = 9L, 
`-0,12%` = 6L, `-0,13%` = 9L, `-0,14%` = 11L, `-0,15%` = 4L, 
`-0,16%` = 8L, `-0,17%` = 6L, `-0,18%` = 10L, `-0,19%` = 5L), 
  .Dim = 20L, .Dimnames = list(
    dado = c("-0,00%", "-0,01%", "-0,02%", "-0,03%", "-0,04%", 
    "-0,05%", "-0,06%", "-0,07%", "-0,08%", "-0,09%", "-0,10%", 
    "-0,11%", "-0,12%", "-0,13%", "-0,14%", "-0,15%", "-0,16%", 
    "-0,17%", "-0,18%", "-0,19%")), class = "table")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Talvez `i <- order(as.numeric(names(freq))); barplot(freq[i])`.

Comment: tem o link da base de dados usada? posso testar aqui.

Comment: Pode, por favor, **editar a pergunta** com a saída de `dput(freq)` ou, se a base for muito grande, de `dput(head(freq, 20))`? Se as decimais estão com vírgulas, eses valores devem ter sido lidos como `"factor"`. Tem a certeza que o separador de colunas é `sep = ","`? E `read.csv` já tem um data.frame como saída, a instrução seguinte não faz nada.

Comment: https://br.investing.com/indices/bovespa-historical-data essa é a base utilizada, peguei a variação dos ultimos 10 anos para plotar a última linha que é de variação diária Breweron.

Comment: Rui, é isso mesmo, as variações estão com vírgulas, e o programa entende número positivo os negativos e ordena considerando "-0,0%" menor que "-2,0%" por exemplo.

Comment: Tentei colocar as.numeric mas ele retorna valores aleatórios, não entendi!

Answer (score 2):

O problema é que você está criando um gráfico que tem uma variável texto para o que deveria ser uma variável numérica. E não há como ser diferente na medida em que você confia no "nome" das variáveis, que sempre será um texto.

É possível resolver o problema específico apresentado acima invertendo o vetor com a função `rev()`.

```
barplot(rev(sopt), ylab="Frequência", xlab = "Retornos diários do Ibovespa")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas essa solução não é garantia de resolver adequadamente o problema, se adicionássemos outros elementos fora de ordem (-2% antes do -1%) no vetor `freq`, o resultado seria diferente do esperado.

```
barplot(rev(c(freq, c("-2%" = 3, "-1%" = 5))), 
        ylab="Frequência", xlab = "Retornos diários do Ibovespa")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que precisamos fazer é determinar a ordem dos dados que serão desenhados de acordo com seu nome (e ai deve valer uma ordenação numérica).

```
percentual <- as.numeric(sub(',', '.', sub('%', '', names(freq))))

# Ou, usando readr
percentual <- readr::parse_number(
  names(freq), locale = readr::locale(decimal_mark = ",")
)

ordem <- order(percentual)
barplot(freq[ordem])
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Observe que essa nova forma é robusta a vetores bagunçados e não sofre dos problemas da segunda figura (-1% "menor" que -2%):

```
freq2 <- c(freq, c("-2%" = 3, "-1%" = 5))
percentual2 <- readr::parse_number(
  names(freq2), locale = readr::locale(decimal_mark = ",")
)
ordem2 <- order(percentual2)
barplot(freq2[ordem2])
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## O `ggplot2`

Dito tudo isso, acho muito melhor confiar em `data.frames` e no sistema de gráficos do `ggplot2`.

```
# repetir o percentual pelo numero de vezes que aparece
# engenharia reversa do "table" da pergunta
variacoes <- rep(percentual, freq)

df <- data.frame(var = variacoes)

head(df)

#>     var
#> 1  0.00
#> 2  0.00
#> 3  0.00
#> 4  0.00
#> 5 -0.01
#> 6 -0.01
```

E então com esse `data.frame` em mãos, que deve ser parecido com seu `data.frame` original, basta usar o `geom_bar` do [ggplot2](/questions/tagged/ggplot2) que vai ordenar as barras de acordo com a variável numérica `var`.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(var)) +
 geom_bar()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Os dados de Var foram lidos como fator por causa do símbolo de porcentagem. Não há uma maneira de ler como *numeric* usando read.table, precisa carregar os dados para depois tratar a string e converter:

```
dados_ibov <- read.csv2('treinosr/Ibovespa_datah.csv')

dados_ibov$Var <- as.numeric(sub(',', '.', sub('%', '', dados_ibov$Var)))
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Carlos, mais ainda retorna o erro ao ler-se a segunda linha:                       > dados_ibov$Var. <- as.numeric(sub(',', '.', sub('%', '', dados_ibov$Var)))
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, Var., value = numeric(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 2759

Comment: Rode dput(head(dados_ibov)) e adicione o resultado à sua pergunta.\, junto com o resultado do dput(freq).